# Access Denied 403 error when using "Get User Profile V2" action in Microsoft Flow

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow that is triggered when a form is submitted. As part of this flow, it takes the "Respondent's Email" and uses the flow action "Get User Profile V2" to extract the "Given Name" property from email address. This name is then used to send custom emails.

This flow had been working fine for during our trial and development phase. I tried it yesterday with a real user and it has just stopped at this step; "Get User Profile V2". I am getting the "Access Denied" error even if I submit the form myself. I am not aware of anything that has changed. I have done some digging and others who came across similar issues have mentioned an issue with Sharepoint site collection.

Here is [a link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/I-Found-A-Bug/Get-User-Profile-V2-Access-Denied/m-p/188618#M3367) to another post with similar issue. But my flow is not connected to any Sharepoint site etc.

I am no expert in flow or sharepoint. Could someone please explain what could possibly be the reason for it to suddenly fall on its back.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you try recreating the `Office 365 Users` connection? Definitely it's worth a try. Then you will be asked for choosing it in your flow by all `Office 365 Users` actions

[image]

When comes to possible SharePoint conflict/influence - our MS Flow creator account does not even have an access to main site collection so maybe this is not applicable to each case.

Comment: Hi @nervuzz, I have tried but unfortunately it did not work and I am still seeing the same error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar issue, for me worked using "Search for user" instead of "get user profile".